# Why I can not use Chart.js typescript react (Not Display)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, chart.js

I have two files which include Chartport.tsx and myportfolio.tsx The code is down below
When I use Chartport components in myportfolio.tsx the page disappears. I don't know why this is happening. It looks like there is some problem with Chartport.tsx file.

Chartport.tsx
This file represent the piechart.

```js
import React from 'react'
import {Pie} from "react-chartjs-2"

const Chartport = () => {
  return (
    <Pie
    data={{
      labels: ['red', 'blue','yellow'],
      datasets: [{ 
        label: 'colors', 
        data: [300,50,100],
        backgroundColor:[
        'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
        'rgb(54, 162, 235)',
        'rgb(255, 205, 86)'
        ] 
    }],
    }}
    />
  )
}

export default Chartport
```

Myportfolio.tsx

```js
import React from 'react'

import myphoto from '../../assets/handsomeboy.jpg'

import Button from '../../globalcomponents/Button'
import Tableport from './components/Tableport'

import Layout from '../../globalcomponents/Layout'
import Chartport from './components/Chartport'
const myportfolio = () => {

  const test= () =>{
    console.log("thank you");
    }
  const test2= () =>{
    console.log("t");
    }


  return (
    <Layout>
      <div className="m-4 flex items-center">
        <div className="w-60 m-7">
          <img className="rounded-full" src={myphoto} alt='myphoto' width="150" height="200"></img>
        </div>
        <div className="m-14">
          <h1 className="mt-3 font-semibold text-3xl">Nasvirat</h1>
          <h3 className="mt-3 font-normal text-xl">Rank #30</h3>
          <h3 className="mt-3 font-nomral text-xl">Total Balance: 3000 USD</h3>
          <div className="flex">
            <Button fn={test} text="mypost" color="#8236FD"/>
            <Button fn={test2} text="cash report" color="#8236FD"/>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div>
        
        </div>
          </div>

      <div className="ml-16">
        <div className="flex items-center">
          <h3 className="font-semibold text-2xl">Holding</h3>
          <Button fn={test}  text="add" color="#0E0741"/>
        </div>
        <Tableport/>
        <div>
          <Chartport/>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Layout>
  )
}

export default myportfolio
```

"chart.js": "^3.9.1",
"react": "^18.2.0",
"react-chartjs-2": "^4.3.1",